# Как отлаживать сам React Native в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, отладка, react-native, android-debug

Не понимаю, как нужно открыть React Native проект в Android Studio, чтобы была возможность зайти в нужный класс в `./node_modules/react-native` и поставить точку останова. И другой вопрос наперёд, который я предвижу. Мне нужно будет как-то подключиться к процессу, который был порожден от `react-native run-android`?

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо за опечатку, но лучше бы ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо воспользоваться дебаггером для javascript, подробно описано тут https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging
я бы порекомендовал использовать один из редакторов с поддержкой react-native, к примеру vscode один из самых популярных. в нем легко сконфигурировать дебаггер и подключиться к процессу в режиме отладки.

пример конфигурации "Attach to packager" (созданная вами может отличаться, создается из присета)

```
{
  "name": "Attach to packager",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
  "type": "reactnative",
  "request": "attach",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
  "port": "8081"
}
```

далее начать отладку, открыть необходимый файл, поставить точку остановы

```
react-native start (запускаем упаковщик)
react-native run-android (собираем проект, подключаемся упаковщику за новым бандлом)
```

или дебаггером android studio если вопрос в нативных модулях на java